# close window based on kCGWindowName value

Tags: swift, macos

but I'm not new to programming. I'm trying to have an always running menubar app listen for a specific window in an application to be opened and then close that window, but not the application. Here is my current approach, it is mostly a mix of other SO answers I found.

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // listener for when user switches applications
    NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                                                                 selector: #selector(activated),
                                                                 name: NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification,
                                                                 object: nil)
}

func activated(notification: NSNotification) {

    // i feel like i should be using that NSNotification but I'm not

    let options = CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: CGWindowListOption.ExcludeDesktopElements, CGWindowListOption.OptionOnScreenOnly)
    let windowListInfo = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, CGWindowID(0))
    let infoList = windowListInfo as NSArray? as? [[String: AnyObject]]

    for item in infoList! {

        // if i find the window i want to close
        if item[kCGWindowName as String] == "Warnings" {
            // close window item[kCGWindowName]
        }

    }
```

My question is, if I am even doing any of this right, how do I close the window based off of having its windowListInfo?

Also, the `item[kCGWindowName as String]` is saying `Cannot convert value of type 'AnyObject?' to expected argument type String.` How would I go about checking windows for the name I want without casting to a String? I have called print() on all objects in infoList and have seen a kCGWindowName value with the name of the window I am looking for, so I know its there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no easy way to do this. Your best bet would probably be to use the Accessibility APIs rather than CGWindowList.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @KenThomases . Do you mind pointing me in the right direction or giving me some tips on the Accessibility API? I've never used it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the accessibility API:

- You need to enable accessibility for your application or **Xcode** (if
  you test your application from Xcode).
- Open the  "**Security & Privacy**" pane on the "System Preferences"
  window. Click the "**Privacy**" tab.
- Select "**Accessibility**" from the list in the left pane.
- Click the lock icon to make changes.
- Drag/drop your application or **Xcode** in the right pane.

---

Here's an example of the swift code (***Swift version 2.2***) to simulate a click on the red button of the window whose the title start with "**Warnings**":

```
func activated(notification: NSNotification) {
    if (notification.userInfo![NSWorkspaceApplicationKey]!.localizedName) == "Pages" { // when "Pages" application is active only
        let myApp = AXUIElementCreateApplication(notification.userInfo![NSWorkspaceApplicationKey]!.processIdentifier).takeUnretainedValue()
        let val1 = UnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>.alloc(1)

        if AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(myApp, kAXWindowsAttribute, val1).rawValue == 0 { // get windows of the "Pages" application
            let windowList = val1.memory as? [AXUIElement] ?? []
            for w in windowList { // loop each window, get the title of the window, and check if the title starts with "Warning"
                if AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(w, kAXTitleAttribute, val1).rawValue == 0 && (val1.memory as! String).hasPrefix("Warnings") {
                    if AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(w, kAXCloseButtonAttribute, val1).rawValue == 0 {// get the red button of the window
                        AXUIElementPerformAction(val1.memory as! AXUIElement, kAXPressAction); // close the window
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        val1.dealloc(1)
    }
}
```

To check the title equal "**Warnings**": use `val1.memory as! String == "Warnings"`

---

Informations on the `infoList` from your code:

> How would I go about checking windows for the name I want without
>   casting to a String?

Use a string instead of the constant, like this:

```
 if item["kCGWindowName"]! as! String == "Warnings" {
```