# Hiding windows from other applications?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-graphics

I need to hide specific windows from other apps running on macOS.

We can hide an entire application like this:

```swift
NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications[0].hide()
```

but this hides **all** windows for the app.

Core Graphics provides a method to obtain window data for all open windows:

```swift
let windows = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo([.optionAll], kCGNullWindowID) as! [[CFString : Any]]
```

This dictionary contains info like window ID, layer and bounds, but I see no method for hiding/minimizing.

Is it possible to hide a specific window using Core Graphics or another API?

Comment: I don't know an easier way.  At least, you can use the window ID to specify a window belonging to another application.  And you should be able to close it through AppleScript.

Comment: See [OSX / Objective C Window Management: manipulate the frames & visibility of other applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010638/osx-objective-c-window-management-manipulate-the-frames-visibility-of-other). Set the `kAXMinimizedAttribute` attribute instead of the `kAXPositionAttribute` attribute.

Comment: Or see [close window based on kCGWindowName value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38671557/close-window-based-on-kcgwindowname-value). Copy the `kAXMinimizeButtonAttribute` instead of the `kAXCloseButtonAttribute`.